# Why tensorflow.keras and tensorflow.python.keras does not work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, tensorflow2.0

When I import the module it says that there is an invalid sintax.

```
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

For all of this imports I got the same error : invalid sintax.
I upgraded my pycharm till the latest version , and the interpreter is Python 3.8 .

The traceback :

```
  File "E:/pythonProject/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you post the full Traceback (error), please?

Comment: The version of TensorFlow you installed does not support  python 3.8, how exactly did you install it?

Comment: I installed it from File->Settings->Python Interpreter . And  I also tried to install with : pip install tensorflow.

Comment: I did the same for python interpreter 3.9 .. but I read somewhere that tensorflow is not supported only till the version 3.8.*

Answer (score 0):

Your pycharm is not at fault for an invalid syntax.

The reason why you are getting an error is because of the tensorflow.python.keras.layers the right way to write it is tensorflow.keras.layers see documentation here
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers

Comment: But even if I write in this way : tensorflow.keras.models . I got the same error : invalid sintax

Comment: What's your tensorflow version?

Comment: The Version 1.8.0

Comment: And if I want to upgrade the tensorflow with command : "pip install tensorflow --upgrade ". It tells me that : " Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow ... "

Comment: Oh that's probably your error then you are using the syntax for tensorflow 2.0+ either upgrade to the latest version or read the documentation for how to use tensorflow 1.x

Comment: Can you tell me please how to upgrade it ? Because when I type the command : pip install tensorflow --upgrade it tells me that "Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow ..."  .

Comment: And with the command : pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0 it tells me that there is no matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0 .. And I got this message for all the version , 2.4.1 ,2.4.0..

Comment: You should probably write a new question for this, but here's the official documentation on how to install tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-install

Comment: Also I would recommend that you try the virtual environment for your tensorflow installation, maybe you have some leftovers from tensorflow 1.x that are causing you issues and a virtual environment would bypass those issues (although maybe not the best to solve a problem)

Comment: @OnlyAUser What's your pip version? Does it keep up to date? Try upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` if you couldn't install tensorflow 2.